# Uncaught TypeError in javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys just want to ask I always got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maparea' of undefined
```

When I tried to display my pdf page in a window pop up. In my previous page it is working. But when i copied and paste the code in my other pages it doesn't display my popup window.

Here' what i did:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-SMALL" type="button" onClick='targetitem = document.forms[0].maparea; dataitem = window.open("<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/supplier_controller/displaySupplierPdf","dataitem", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes"); dataitem.targetitem = targetitem' value="PRINT" />
```

That's all guys I hope you can help me.

Comment: why do you have all that javascript code inline? are you using jquery? then bind to the element's click event using `$('input').click(function(){...});`

Comment: Look at the code that accesses `maparea`... it tries to read the first form on the page. If your page has no forms, it will obviously fail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the that I am missing the document form. So when I added the  tag it display my PDF. Thanks guys for the response.